# pyspark cython gets file.so too short

Tags: pyspark, cython

I am following the documentation here

https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/faq/cython.html

I can get this short sample code to work, but when incorporating into my longer code, I get this

```
  File "./jobs.zip/jobs/util.py", line 51, in wrapped
    cython_function_ = getattr(__import__(module), method)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py", line 458, in load_module
    language_level=self.language_level)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py", line 233, in load_module
    exec("raise exc, None, tb", {'exc': exc, 'tb': tb})
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py", line 216, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_dynamic(name, so_path)
ImportError: Building module cython_util failed: ['ImportError: /home/.pyxbld/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cython_util.so: file too short\n']

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Yet, after this error the spark program seems to keep running. Any one knows what the heck is this complain? How can the .so file be too short? Can I ignore it and move on since the program continues to run.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your stack trace, it seems you have code running in parallel. And the parallel code is importing Cython code via `pyximport.install`.

I've encountered a Cython/pyximport bug in a very similar scenario and I've opened a bug in github:
https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/5331

For a workaround, the Cython import could be put in an [ilock](https://github.com/symonsoft/ilock) block.